Why does Pulumi give this error message that says terraform apply?
I am trying to run pulumi destroy on a cloud run resource that does not have delete protection. But I am getting the following error:-
cannot destroy service without setting deletion_protection=false and running terraform apply

Given I am using Pulumi and not Terraform why does the error message mention terraform apply?

One of the features of Pulumi is that it allows you to use any terraform provider with it. The Pulumi provider you're using for GCP is actually using Terraform's Google provider behind the scenes. Given the Terraform provider is mainly built for Terraform it has an error message that describes how to solve the particular issue for Terraform.
In your case to solve the issue you just need to set deletion_protection=false for your Cloud run resource before running pulumi destroy (You might potentially need to run pulumi up first to ensure the state has the protection disabled first).
